# Full Refresh of page - Ctrl+F5

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I would like to know how to implement a "ctrl+f5" command into my HTML page. I can use javascript or html.

It should be run only when people click in a link.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an elegant way to force browsers to reload cached CSS/JS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload for a documentation

Comment: See  [javascript - Is $window.location.reload(true) the equivalent of CTRL+F5? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630232/6264260)  The main difference: Ctrl-F5 will cause all the attached resources also to reload (scripts, images ...) while the reload(true) will not, the main page (html) will be requested but resources can still be loaded from cache.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<strike>You should be able to use this javascript to suite your need:</strike>

`onClick="window.location.reload(true)"`

`window.location.reload(true)` has been deprecated. You can use:

`window.location.href = window.location.href`

Comment: Please notice, that this may reload the site from the cache... Use reload(true) if you want a real site reload.

Comment: Also note that this won't reload any external resources like images ecc.

Comment: if we set the parameter to false... what's the difference?

Comment: What's the definite solution? Many times customer has cached version of a web site. We enabled a web service to detect if there is a new version on Page mount. In case there is a new one, we want to enable a refresh link that will take a new (non cached) version

Answer (score 10):

Something like this?

```
<a href="document.location.reload(true);document.location='/mylink'">Click here to refresh the page</a>
```

Comment: That's nice, but I would like to embed it in another link. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

you can create a button for refresh , add the following code into your html page

```
<a href="JavaScript: location.reload(true);">Refresh page</a>
```

Comment: <input type="button" value="Refresh page" onclick="location.reload(true);" />

Comment: and you should add this :)

Answer (score 0):

for automatically refresh you can use a function , like this !

```
<html>
   <head>
      
      <script type = "text/JavaScript">
         <!--
            function AutoRefresh( t ) {
               setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
            }
         //-->
      </script>
      
   </head>


<div id="54666751046"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/OCINE?data[rnddiv]=54666751046&data[responsive]=yes&muted=true&autoplay=true"></script></div> 
   
   <body onload = "JavaScript:AutoRefresh(5000);">
      <p>This page will refresh every 5 seconds.</p>
   </body>
   
</html>
```