# Is $window.location.reload(true) the equivalent of CTRL+F5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-cache

I am attempting to build a "version updated" component that will show a banner when the website has been updated and prompt a user to reload. Unfortunately when some users reload their page is cached so it does not update properly.  Previously we have told them to press CTRL+F5 but I am looking for a way to do this programatically.

I am using the following code

```
this.$window.location.reload(true);
```

Whose function signature is declared like so:

```
reload(forcedReload?: boolean): void;
```

Does this mean that it will skip the cache? When I try it out a CTRL+F5 the index.html shows a 200 in the Network tab of Chrome but using `$window.location.reload(true)` shows a 304 [Not Modified]

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), it seems so. But there might be some differences in the ctrl + F5 process other than ignoring the cache.

Comment: If you version your resource and script files during your build process, you can still use `$window.location.reload()` to get the latest version always.

Comment: @Gaara Thank you, I version all my resources so it sounds like this would work

Comment: Manage chache settings on your server - F5 should be enough.

Comment: @NisargShah Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it. After testing more this works as per the documentation, thank you

Comment: @Chris Done! Please feel free to add to it if you have discovered something that might help others. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) the `forcedReload` parameter in `window.location.reload`, when set to `true`:

> ... causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is
>   false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not (proven by testing)

The main difference: `Ctrl-F5` will cause all the attached resources also to reload (scripts, images ...) while the `reload(true)` will not, the main page (html) will be requested but resources can still be loaded from cache

Comment: The main page is the only thing I want to refresh.

Comment: The page will be refreshed with both ways, what 304 means (if that's the critical point) is that the server decides that the cached page is the same as the actual page

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like:

```
$window.location.href = currentUrl + '?' + new Date().getTime();
```

That should force a cold refresh.

Comment: You should check the URL for existing parameters and anchors