# What command that equivalent with Shift + F5 for JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear cache and hard reload browser but how to do that using JS/jQuery command when the document is ready?

My reference:

1. [1st Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page#:%7E:text=Try%20to%20use%3A,be%20reloaded%20from%20the%20server.)
2. [2nd Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841312/full-refresh-of-page-ctrlf5/22841411)
3. [3rd Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721704/window-location-reload-with-clear-cache/5722855)

I have tried below but not working except commented with `this one` but it continuously reload with never stop. Why this happen? How to make it just reload 1 time only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // window.location.reload(false);
    // document.location.reload(true);
    // window.location.reload(true);
    // window.location.href = window.location.href;
    // location.reload(true); //this one
});
```

Updated: Googling and tried this but not working.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("origin", window.location.href);

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.href == sessionStorage.getItem("origin")){
        window.location.reload();
        sessionStorage.removeItem('origin');
    }
});
```

Comment: to make it reload one time only, you'd have to store some information saying that you've reloaded before. So, perhaps before you call `location.reload`, you could set some variable in SessionStorage, and then check if that is set and only reload if it's not set

Comment: hi, i am so sorry and no idea how to do that.

Comment: just google `sessionStorage`, it's pretty easy to deal with

Comment: Actually, another option is to look at the `document.referrer` attribute -- if it's equal to `location.href`, don't reload, otherwise do reload

Comment: This is because, when you reload, the referrer is equal to the current href (not sure if you'll need to consider query parameters at all, but generally this will work)

Comment: i have google and tried updated posting above but not working.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: Don't try to do this with JS. Set proper cache control headers on your HTTP resources in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `localStorage` for that, simply check whether your `localStorage` has a value or not. If not, reload first and then set a value. Have a look at the example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var reload = localStorage.getItem('reload');

    console.log(reload);

    if (reload === null) {
        location.reload(true);
        localStorage.setItem('reload', "stop");
    }

});
```